# Does "randomWhere" sample the agent's population?

Tags: anylogic

Can someone indicate or explain the possibility of the function `randomWhere` overlooking the whole population when looking for an agent. In other words, does `randomWhere` sample the agents' population in any case?

I am matching agents base on age conditions using `randomWhere`. However, I have noticed that the function returns `null` despite the availability of candidate agents. My naïve workaround to this issue is to call the function more than once to maximise the matching process. Any suggestions to this issue?

Regards,
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the help documentation, `randomWhere` does sample across the entire population.

https://anylogic.help/anylogic/stochastic/selecting-random.html#element-from-collection

If your function is returning `null` then most likely there is something wrong in the logic or the setup